# Using apprarmor/grsec to gain capabilities for file

Tags: linux, apparmor, grsecurity

I know that using apparmor, one can reduce process capabilities(7). But is it possible to gain them?

For example: `ping` requires `CAP_NET_RAW`. It's binary has **no** suid set and doesn't have any file capabilities. Is it possible to give `CAP_NET_RAW` to it, without touching binary itself? (eg. with creating apparmor rule)

Grsecurity seem to have RBAC system too, so maybe it is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

AppArmor works in addition to the standard Linux permission checks, not instead of.  It can't grant any privilege the program didn't already have.